# How can I determine the position a pattern matched in a string?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to match a pattern with this format `/vX.X.X/` where X a number. For example: `/v1.1.1/` and `/v1.0.300/`. After matching the pattern, how can I get the position in the string where I found the pattern?

Comment: It's really weird to want the position of a match. Was is it you [ultimately want](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach you take depends on what you are trying to accomplish and the rest of the stuff around the problem. Since you haven't said anything about this, here's a shotgun blast of different ideas. Not all of them may be appropriate for what you are doing.

---

The `@-` special variable has the offsets for the starting position of
the match groups. The first element is the start of the entire match,
the second element (index 1) is the start of the `$1` match, and so
on. If your pattern is the entire string you want, then you can use
the first element in that array:

```
if( $string =~ /\bv\d+\.\d+\.\d+\b/ ) {
    my $position = $-[0];
    say "Position is $position";
    }
```

If you have other stuff around you pattern and the stuff you want is
in the first match group, you can use the second element (remember
that match groups are numbered by the order of the opening parens):

```
if( $string =~ /before (v\d+\.\d+\.\d+) after/ ) {
    my $position = $-[1];
    say "Position is $position";
    }
```

When your pattern changes, you may need to update with element you
use.

There's also `@+` that works the same but has the ending position. I
have a bunch of examples of this in the first edition of [Mastering
Perl](https://www.masteringperl.org). I save it for that book because
I find that many people get confused on which element corresponds to
which part of the pattern. Consider if you'll remember this later.

You can use `index` to get the position of the matched string:

```
if( $string =~ /\b(v\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\b/ ) {
    my $matched = $1;
    my $position = index( $string, $matched );
    say "Position is $position";
    }
```

Using the `/p` flag and `${^PREMATCH}` variable from Perl v5.10, count
the positions before the matched part of the string:

```
use v5.10;

if( $string =~ /\bv\d+\.\d+\.\d+\b/p ) {
    my $position = length ${^PREMATCH};
    say "Position is $position";
    }
```

Use the `/g` flag in scalar context and Perl remembers the string
position where the match ended. Subtract the match length to see
where the match started:

```
if( $string =~ /\b(v\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\b/g ) {
    my $matched = $1;
    my $position = pos( $string ) - length($1);
    say "Position is $position";
    }
```

If there can be multiple matches per string, you'll have to adjust
these. One way uses a `while` loops since condition is still a scalar
context:

```
while( $string =~ /\b(v\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\b/g ) {
    my $matched = $1;
    my $position = pos( $string ) - length($1);
    say "Position is $position";
    }
```

Comment: Did you forget about `$-[0]`?

Comment: `\d` matches far more than `[0-9]` unless `/a` is used.

Comment: I didn't feel the need to clutter the issue with the rest of the language. And I wouldn't wish `$-[0]` on anyone.

Comment: But you'd wish for people to use `index`??? Aside from having to scan the string a second time (though faster the second time), it won't always give the right answer. (It will for the OP, though.)

Comment: You can always use `use English` to give `@-` a friendlier name

Comment: Yes, I'd rather a complete beginner use index. From teaching `@-` in my Mastering Perl classes, I find that off by one errors are common. And, people tend to forget how the variable works when they don't think about it. I'd rather people understand their code even if it's a little inefficient.

Comment: It's not the inefficiency that concerns me, it's the possibility of not finding the right match. This can happen when zero-width assertions (e.g. `^`, `$`, `\z`, `\b`, `(?=)`) or some directives (e.g. `\K`) are used, which account for a significant portion of the patterns I write. More importantly, it can happen for your very own solution since you used `\b`. For example, **if `$string` contains `v4.5.6a v4.5.6`, your solutions will all output `8` except the `index` solution which will output `0`.**

Answer (score 7):

`@-` contains the offsets at which the match and captures were found.

- `$-[0]` is the offset at which the pattern matched.
- `$-[1]` is the offset at which the first capture matched.
- `$-[2]` is the offset at which the second capture matched.
- etc.

As such, you can use the following:

```
if ( $s =~ m{/v\d+\.\d+\.\d+/}a ) {
   say "Matched at position $-[0]";
}
```

Comment: and how can I find then the index of that matched pattern inside the line? I couldn't print the matched pattern.

Comment: @OmarCharfeddine If you just want the matched section, use [capture groups](https://perldoc.pl/perlretut#Extracting-matches), you don't need indexes.

Comment: @Grinnz, Yeah, that's why I left a comment mentioning this might be an XY Problem above